# Does SSDT Unit Test Configuration Override Work In VS 2015?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

So I've been working with SSDT unit tests for years, and one of my biggest bug-bears was how you could only have one configuration for the test project. If you wanted to run it against a different connection, you had to update the configuration file.

Today I stumbled across this blog post which suggests that actually, you can create *machinename*.sqlunittest.config files which override the config file : http://dataidol.com/jamesduggan/2015/09/05/2559/.

This is also mentioned on the Microsoft documentation here (although here it says *machinename*.sqluni**ttt**est.config) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-data-tools/jj851202(v=vs.103)

This was a very exciting discovery, but I've spent all afternoon trying to implement it for one of our existing unit test projects which was created in VS 2015, and nothing seems to work; it never picks up the override file, it just uses the config file which gets generated from app.config.

I can't find any other references to this method of overriding the configuration, and these only refer to VS 2010, VS 2012 and VS 2013.

So what I want to know is, has anyone actually implemented this in VS 2015, and if so, did they have to do anything different to what is documented in those links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to take a fresh look at this problem today, and I've figured out where I was going wrong. It seems like this only works in VSTest; it doesn't seem to work in MSTest, which is what I was trying to do the other day.

So I've confirmed that it is possible to implement configuration override in VS 2015.